# how to display @feathersjs-client results in Angular Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I wanted to implement a feature in the front-end that will check the data from the form if it exist or not. I called the checking from the service. All I wanted was to check if the data exist with the id query .

I just wanted to check if it exist , do I need to map it ? when all I just want to know is if the data exist based on the query ? Any advice ?

How do I check if the checking service returns the correct data ?

Any advice ? Thanks.  feel free to ask any question

I am using angular and featherjs

## Snippet[form component]

```
 save(): void {

    if (this.respondents.length === 1) {
      const existing = this.requestFormService.checking(this.form);
      console.log("existing :" ,existing)
```

## Snippet Service

```
checking(formGroup: FormGroup): Observable<PeopleRequest[]> {
    return from(this.feathers.service('people-requests').find<PeopleRequest>({
        query: {
          id: 18967,
        }
      }))
      .pipe(
        map((result) => result.data)
      );
  }
```

Comment: you should subscribe to `checking(...)` inside `save`, otherwise you will never get a result, but only the subscription. if you want to log the 'result' of your `checking(...)` you need to log it inside the next handler.

Comment: can you provide some exmplae acincognito ?

Comment: can you post what `this.service.find` does? What does it return, if it exists/not exists?

Comment: this.service = this.feathers.service('sample-data');

Comment: this connects from the model in the backend